# What is the specific behavior of the 'Save Taskbar Previews' option?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, taskbar, window

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> → Advanced System Settings → Performance, Settings → 'Save Taskbar Previews'

'Save Taskbar Previews' changes the effect of hovering over windows in the taskbar: hovering over windows will either display a live preview (disabled) or a cached image of the window's contents (enabled).

If I disable the option, will my computer to continuously redraw all background windows all the time?

I was thinking it might only start redrawing them when the mouse goes over the taskbar, but I have no way of testing this.